# Extracting the first line from pdf text in python

Tags: python, pdf, text

I am splitting the text extracted from pdf by "\n" But having an issue with the position of the string after the split. for some, it is working with [0] and for some, it is [2]. I want to put this in a loop and extract the first line from the page irrespective of the position

Here is my code :

```
for fil in new_pdf_files:
    object = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(fil)
    pdfFileObj = open(fil, 'rb')
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(1)
    s= (pageObj.extractText())
    name =s.split("\n")[0]  
    print(name)
```

pdf text extract

**1st pdf text extract**
" \n \nPIERRE AVENIR 2\n \nSociété Civile de Placement Immobilier au capital de 99\n \n\n \nSiège social\n \n: 167, quai de la "

\n is present before the name for some others it is

**2nd pdf text extract**

"ADVINI\n \n \nSociété anonyme à directoire et \nConseil de surveillance\n \na\nu capita"

No \n is present before the name

In need extract **PIERRE AVENIR 2** and **ADVINI**

Answer (score 1):

Use strip to get rid of leading and trailing spaces first:

```
name =s.strip().split("\n")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
for fil in new_pdf_files:
    object = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(fil)
    pdfFileObj = open(fil, 'rb')
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(1)
    s= (pageObj.extractText())
    name =s.split("\n")
    for i in name:
        if i not in ["", " ", ", "]:
            print(i)
            break
```

I believe looping over the array name as I did above might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to simply use a regular expression to remove any leading characters you want to ignore before using split to get the first line:

```
    import re
    
    for fil in new_pdf_files:
        object = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(fil)
        pdfFileObj = open(fil, 'rb')
        pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
        pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(1)
        s= (pageObj.extractText())
        name = re.sub("^[ ,\n]+", "", s).split("\n")[0]  
        print(name)
```